# sublime command using translate escaping characters incorrectly

Tags: python, regex, windows, sublimetext3

I have an escape and paste command which I use while working in markdown:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+v"], 
    "command": "escape_and_paste", 
    "args": {
        "\\": "\\\\",
        "_" : "\\_",
        "*" : "\\*"
    }
}
```

and the actual command is defined as:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class EscapeAndPasteCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **kwargs):
        # Get the clipboard text
        originalText = textToPaste = sublime.get_clipboard() 

        # Use the arguments as a translation table
        textToPaste = textToPaste.translate(str.maketrans(kwargs))

        # Place the text back into the clipboard and paste in place
        sublime.set_clipboard(textToPaste)
        self.view.run_command("paste")

        # Restore the original text to the clipboard
        sublime.set_clipboard(originalText)
```

What it should do is escape backslashes, underscores and asterisks with a backslash. However it has odd consequences with text like the following:

`"skylling\sdfds and _adst_"` which gets escaped to: `"skylling\\sdfds and \\_adst\\_"` when it should be `"skylling\\sdfds and \_adst\_"`. Not exactly sure why

When I run this test in Python directly I do not get this issue.

```
textToPaste = 'skylling\sdfds and _adst_'
escapay = {
    "\\": "\\\\",
    "_": "\\_",
     "*": "\\*"
 }
print(textToPaste.translate(str.maketrans(escapay)))

skylling\\sdfds and \_adst\_
```

Is this because of how my args are being sent to the my py sublime command or a misunderstanding of how `translate()` works? Running Sublime Text 3 build 3143.

Comment: This seems to work for me in build 3143 as you say it should and not how you're seeing it. Your problem looks suspiciously like the `translate` method makes multiple passes or is sensitive to the order of the input when replacements overlap, but I can't seem to make it fail that way. Have you tried this in a clean reverted environment to see if there is some weird interplay with something else?

Comment: Oddly enough I recall this not being a problem and something that only showed up in the last couple of months. Is the python in Sublime stand-alone or would it react to me updating Python on the compute. I have had this in place for well over a year so there isn't much I could revert to. I will try on another system and see what happens.

Comment: Sublime has it's own internal Python interpreter (3.3.6) that it uses for the plugin environment; it ignores external python installations.  Something to check might be to include `print(originalText)` and `print(textToPaste)` right after the `translate` call, just to verify that an event handler or some other command aren't fiddling with the data behind your back.